# How to debug Kotlin sequences / collections

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Take the following one-liner, which can be expressed as a series of operations on a collection or a sequence:

```
val nums = (10 downTo 1)
        // .asSequence() if we want this to be a sequence
        .filter { it % 2 == 0 }
        .map { it * it }
        .sorted()
        // .asList() if declaring it a sequence

println(nums)   // [4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

Let's say I want to see the elements at each step, they would be (from deduction):

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
[100, 64, 36, 16, 4]
[4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

Unfortunately, there's no good way to either debug this with a debugger or log these values for later inspection. With good functional programming constructs, entire methods can be rewritten as single statements like this but there seems to be no good way to inspect intermediate states, even counts (`10, 5, 5, 5` here).

What's the best way to debug these?

Comment: These are not sequences, but mere collections. Please fix the title not to confuse anyone.

Comment: You need to distinguish between a collection and a sequence. A sequence calculates the list lazily, so there is no [100, 64, 36, 16, 4] at any time during execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the current correct answer is that you want the [Kotlin Sequence Debugger](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10301-kotlin-sequence-debugger) plugin, which lets you use IntelliJ's lovely Java stream debugger with Kotlin sequences.

Note that (unless I'm doing something wrong) it doesn't appear to work with collections, so you will have to convert the collection to a sequence in order to debug it. Easy enough using Iterable.asSequence, and a small price to pay -- you can always revert that change once you are done debugging.

Comment: This is definitely the answer. IDE tool to help with debugging without having to put in logging statements beforehand.

Comment: Since 2019.1 the plugin's features are included in the Kotlin plugin, no need for a separate install

Answer (score 9):

You can log the intermediate values (lists) with

```
fun <T> T.log(): T { println(this); this }

//USAGE:
val nums = (10 downTo 1)
    .filter { it % 2 == 0 }.log()
    .map { it * it }.log()
    .sorted().log()
```

This will work as desired since in your example you work with collections, not sequences. For lazy `Sequence` you need:

```
// coming in 1.1
public fun <T> Sequence<T>.onEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Sequence<T> {
    return map {
        action(it)
        it
    }
}

fun <T> Sequence<T>.log() = onEach {print(it)}

//USAGE:
val nums = (10 downTo 1).asSequance()
    .filter { it % 2 == 0 }
    .map { it * it }.log()
    .sorted()
    .toList()
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet! It's unfortunate, though, that I need to be proactive to add logging (also it makes my code less readable). All the great code conciseness and bug-free-ness does seem to come at this cost.

Comment: This is only a debugging technique. I would not recommend to use it for logging of any kind.

Answer (score 7):

In latest Intellij Idea when adding a breakpoint you have an option to set it to not inspect whole expression but only a Lambda body.

[image]

Then in the debug itself you can see what is happening inside of your Lambda.

[image]

But this is not the only way. You can also use [Run to cursor (Alt + F9)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/debugger-basics.html#d165252e188).

Comment: How does this help to see intermediate collections though?

Answer (score 2):

you may use the `also` inline function to log, print at any sequence stage as [explained by Andrey Breslav at Google I/O '18](https://youtu.be/6P20npkvcb8?t=1589)

```
   (1..10)
        .filter { it % 2 == 0 }
        .also { e -> println(e) /* do your debug or print here */ }
        .map { it * 2 }
        .toList()
```